# What am i missing here in pagefactory during initializing the page objects? Getting NullpointerException during element identification

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I have setup page object model and trying to initialize the web objects using PageFactory.

I have initialized my driver in testBase and extended the page class to this testbase. When I try to run my test case, the below nullpointerexeception is thrown

TestBase.java

```
public class testBase {
    public  WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    public FlightBookingPage FBPage;

    public testBase(){
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/src/main/java"
                    + "/Config/config.properties");
            prop.load(ip);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setDriverPath() {
        if (PlatformUtil.isMac()) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        if (PlatformUtil.isWindows()) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        if (PlatformUtil.isLinux()) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver_linux");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(testUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(testUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

The below code is actual test class which calls the appropriate functions and variables from page class

```
public class FlightBookingTest extends testBase {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {

        FBPage = new FlightBookingPage();
        setDriverPath();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));

    }

    @Test
    public void testThatResultsAppearForAOneWayJourney() {

        FBPage.clickOneWayBtn();
        FBPage.typeOriginCity("Bangalore");
        FBPage.selectOriginCityfromList("Bangalore");
        FBPage.typeDestinCity("Delhi");
        FBPage.selectDestinCityfromList("Delhi");
        FBPage.selectDate();
        FBPage.clickSearch();
        // verify that result appears for the provided journey search

            Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.className("searchSummary")));

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        // close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Below is the page class for the above test

```
public class FlightBookingPage extends testBase {

    // Page Factory - OR:
    @FindBy(id = "OneWay")
    public WebElement oneWayRdBtn;

    @FindBy(id = "FromTag")
    public WebElement fromCitytxtbox;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ui-id-1']/li")
    public List<WebElement> originOptionList;

    @FindBy(id = "toTag")
    public WebElement toCitytxtbox;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ui-id-2']/li")
    public List<WebElement> destinOptionList;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/a")
    public WebElement date;

    @FindBy(id = "SearchBtn")
    public WebElement searchBtn;

    @FindBy(className = "searchSummary")
    public WebElement searchResultsHeadertxt;


    // Initializing the Page Objects:
    public FlightBookingPage(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void clickOneWayBtn() {
        oneWayRdBtn.click();
    }

    public void typeOriginCity(String origin) {
        fromCitytxtbox.clear();
        fromCitytxtbox.sendKeys(origin);
    }

    public void selectOriginCityfromList(String origin) {
        for (WebElement list : originOptionList) {
            if (list.getText().contains(origin)) {
                list.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void typeDestinCity(String destin) {
        toCitytxtbox.clear();
        toCitytxtbox.sendKeys(destin);
    }

    public void selectDestinCityfromList(String destin) {
        for (WebElement list : destinOptionList) {
            if (list.getText().contains(destin)) {
                list.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void selectDate() {
        date.click();
    }

    public void clickSearch() {
        searchBtn.click();
    }

    public WebElement verifySearchSummaryHeader() {
        return searchResultsHeadertxt;
    }

}
```

I am getting the below error message as soon the focus turns to this block

```
public void clickOneWayBtn() {
        oneWayRdBtn.click();
    }
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.click(Unknown Source)
    at Pages.FlightBookingPage.clickOneWayBtn(FlightBookingPage.java:45)
    at FlightBookingTest.testThatResultsAppearForAOneWayJourney(FlightBookingTest.java:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the below line of code in testBase class

```
public  WebDriver driver;
```

To

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

**Try below in Page class:**

In your page class kindly create a constructor

```
WebDriver driver;

public FlightBookingPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
```

Comment: This was already tried and failed. Got the same error with static driver.

Comment: Create a constructor in page class and pass the driver. Code updated.

Comment: this is really bad advice, don't just make things static, it has far reaching consequences.

Comment: As for the second bit of advice, the Page object extends testBase and as a result inherits the driver object.  You don't need to pass something that is inherited in via the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Swapped the position of initiation of new FlightBookingPage and setDriverPath(). It worked.

Updated code below:

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        setDriverPath();
        FBPage = new FlightBookingPage();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
}
```

Comment: This is because the method setDriverPath is instantiating your driver object.  Your FBPage method expects the driver object to be instantiated in advance because it binds the driver object to the page factory class.  If you don't call setDriverPath before creating a new instance of your Page object you are effectively trying to bind a null driver object to the page factory class which will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please try swapping your **`FBPage = new FlightBookingPage();`** and 
        **`setDriverPath();`** so that value of driver will be instantiated.

Change your code to:

```
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        setDriverPath();    
        FBPage = new FlightBookingPage();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }
```